# Sending object as a mail body in nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, nodemailer

can i send an object key, value pair as a message text in node mailer message object?
Its only accepts a plain text but i want to send an object??
This is the error its shows =>
The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received an instance of Object.

```
    const message = {
        from: email,
        to: req.body.toEmail,
        subject: req.body.subject,
        text: req.body.message
    };
    transporter.sendMail(message, function (err, info) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log(info)
            res.status(200).send(info)
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first convert the object into a string using `JSON.stringify`

```
const message = {
    from: email,
    to: req.body.toEmail,
    subject: req.body.subject,
    text: req.body.message
};

let stringMessage = JSON.stringify(message);
```

Next you can send the object as a string.

```
transporter.sendMail( stringMessage , function(err , info){
  // Callback
})
```